# Error initializing the application with Spring Security: net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache not found

Tags: java, spring, grails, acl, ehcache

I want to use the [Spring Security ACL plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-acl) with mongodb.

When I run my app I get the following error:

```
2014-06-15 14:08:04,325 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache
Message: net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache
    Line | Method
->> 2451 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1810 | getDeclaredMethods        in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache
->>  175 | findClass                 in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    423 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    147 | loadClass . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    356 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   2451 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
|   1810 | getDeclaredMethods        in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

How should I run this?

Comment: you are missing the ehacache.jar in your setup, or there are several of them, causing the version conflict

Comment: @injecteer Could you post the link to the ehacache.jar on maven central please?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.8.3

Comment: great if you post this as an answer I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ehcache.jar in your setup, or there are several of them, causing the version conflict.

You can find the [latest ehcache.jar on the Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.8.3)